# Importing effects error

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I started learning today 3D drawing, following this tut:

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/The_first_triangle.php

There is the file effects.fx which is provided in the first page of the tutorial.

But, for some reason, I get this error when debugging:

Error: Both a vertex shader and pixel shader must be set on the device before any draw operations may be performed.

I searched google for a solution, but none worked.

Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the draw method put in:

```
foreach(EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, 1, 
    VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
}
```